# Moving Rails app to production with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I'm on a VPS.  I created a new rails app with `rails new rails_app -d mysql`.
I'm running nginx with passenger. I'm running Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3. In my nginx.conf file I added the following to the `server` directive:

```
listen       80;
server_name  www.mydomain.com;
passenger_enabled on;
root /home/mike/www/rails_app/public;
rails_env production;
```

When I point to www.mydomain.com I see Welcome aboard You’re riding Ruby on Rails!.  When I click on About your application’s environment I get this error:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
```

When I check my production.log I see this error and don't know what to do with it:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/rails/info/properties")
```

I've been up all night and have read all SO issues similar to this but still I cannot resolve my issue. If I run this in development everything works fine.

**EDIT**

I found this explanation for a Rails 2.3.4 problem: The link fires off an AJAX request to rails/info/properties. The properties action is defined in the Rails::InfoController which lives in /rails/railties/builtin/rails_info/rails/info_controller.rb.

The route doesn't need to be explicitly defined because it conforms to the Rails default route of :controller/:action/:id (although there is no ID in this case and the controller lives within a Rails namespace.)

But I don't see `info_controller.rb` anywhere.

Ok I found this: `config.consider_all_requests_local` is a flag. If true then any error will cause detailed debugging information to be dumped in the HTTP response, and the Rails::Info controller will show the application runtime context in /rails/info/properties. True by default in development and test environments, and false in production mode. For finer-grained control, set this to false and implement local_request? in controllers to specify which requests should provide debugging information on errors.

but setting this to false does nothing.

**EDIT 2**
Ok, I'm an idiot.  Found this somewhere: `You're clicking the "About your application’s environment" link on the Rails default index.html page. This link only works in development environment, not in production.`

And this entire night I thought my Rails app wasn't working. So I guess I'll give up and go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add passenger_base_uri:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    charset utf-8;
    root /www/domain.com/public_html;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_base_uri /blog;
    rails_spawn_method smart;
    rails_env production;
}
```

Also check that passenger and rails work in the same environment (production or development).

Comment: development works fine.  I added passenger_base_uri and still same error.  I don't understand what is trying to route to /rails/info/properties

Answer (score 0):

For those who might encounter this problem in the future, first check your production logs in your server.

1. ssh into your server, `ssh username@serverIP`
2. Check the last 20 or so error messages `tail -20 /home/username/appname/current/log/production.log`
3. If it's a bug in your code (mine was returning an empty array due to an empty db), then fix that bug and run `cap production deploy` once again.
4. Repeat to check for more errors.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem is also faced by me, but I found later wards due to permission, our application is not able to access the specific folder.

Try this command :

```
chmod -R 777 {name of your project folder}/
```